# Runtime error 3134 "Syntax Error in INSERT INTO statement (Access VBA)

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm new to VBA and i'm trying to run the insert into query from 2 tables with selected fields using VBA. However when i run the code i'm getting error = Runtime error 3134 "Syntax Error in INSERT INTO statement

Not sure where is the issue. can someone review the code and advise?

Code -

```
Public Sub sub_import_IDP_Data()

    Dim str_query As String
    Dim rs_filelist As Recordset
    Set rs_filelist = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tbl_IDP_Filenames")

        str_query = "INSERT INTO tbl_IDP_Import"
        str_query = str_query & "SELECT "
        str_query = str_query & ", tbl_IDP_Import_Temp.PRI_INDEX AS [PRI_INDEX]"
        str_query = str_query & ", tbl_IDP_Import_Temp.ROUTING_SET AS [ROUTING_SET]"
        str_query = str_query & ", tbl_IDP_Import_Iemp.START_TIME AS [START_TIME]"
        str_query = str_query & ", tbl_IDP_Import_Temp.STOP_TIME AS [STOP_TIME]"
        str_query = str_query & ", CBYTE(" & tbl_IDP_Import_Temp & ".[HOUR]) AS [HOUR]"
        str_query = str_query & ", CBYTE(" & tbl_IDP_Import_Temp & ".[MINUTE]) AS [MINUTE]"
        str_query = str_query & ", CSNG(IIF(ISNULL(" & tbl_IDP_Import_Temp & ".[F CALLS]), '0', " & tbl_IDP_Import_Temp & ".[F CALLS])) AS [F CALLS]"
        str_query = str_query & ", CSNG(IIF(ISNULL(" & tbl_IDP_Import_Temp & ".[A CALLS]), '0', " & tbl_IDP_Import_Temp & ".[A CALLS])) AS [A CALLS]"
        str_query = str_query & ", " & tbl_IDP_Import_Temp & ".[CALLS DEV%]"
        str_query = str_query & ", CSNG(IIF(ISNULL(" & tbl_IDP_Import_Temp & ".[F AHT]), '0', " & tbl_IDP_Import_Temp & ".[F AHT])) AS [F AHT]"
        str_query = str_query & ", CSNG(IIF(ISNULL(" & tbl_IDP_Import_Temp & ".[A AHT]), '0', " & tbl_IDP_Import_Temp & ".[A AHT])) AS [A AHT]"
        str_query = str_query & ", CDBL(IIF(ISNULL(" & tbl_IDP_Import_Temp & ".[F REQ]), '0', " & tbl_IDP_Import_Temp & ".[F REQ])) AS [F REQ]"
        str_query = str_query & ", CDBL(IIF(ISNULL(" & tbl_IDP_Import_Temp & ".[SCH R]), '0', " & tbl_IDP_Import_Temp & ".[SCH R])) AS [SCH R]"
        str_query = str_query & ", CDBL(IIF(ISNULL(" & tbl_IDP_Import_Temp & ".[SCH O]), '0', " & tbl_IDP_Import_Temp & ".[SCH O])) AS [SCH O]"
        str_query = str_query & ", CDBL(IIF(ISNULL(" & tbl_IDP_Import_Temp & ".[A REQ]), '0', " & tbl_IDP_Import_Temp & ".[A REQ])) AS [A REQ]"
        str_query = str_query & ", CDBL(IIF(ISNULL(" & tbl_IDP_Import_Temp & ".[APS]), '0', " & tbl_IDP_Import_Temp & ".[APS])) AS [APS]"
        str_query = str_query & ", '" & rs_filelist.Fields("fileinout_idp").Value & "' AS [InOut]"
        str_query = str_query & ", #" & CDate(Format(rs_filelist.Fields("datecreated_idp").Value, "m/d/yyyy")) & "# AS [FileDate]"
        str_query = str_query & ", '" & rs_filelist.Fields("filegroup_idp").Value & "' AS [FileGroup]"
        str_query = str_query & "FROM tbl_IDP_Import_Temp"

CurrentDb.Execute str_query

End Sub
```

Comment: You're missing a space between `Insert into tbl` and `Select`. And another on the last line

Comment: Not a syntax error, but you could shorten these lines:  `", CSNG(IIF(ISNULL(" & tbl_IDP_Import_Temp & ".[F AHT]), '0', " & tbl_IDP_Import_Temp & ".[F AHT])) AS [F AHT]"` down to `", CSNG(NZ(" & tbl_IDP_Import_Temp & ".[F AHT],'0'))"`  - do you need the quotes around the `'0'`?  Just `0` should work.

Comment: HI, i tried both solution, but nothing works. I added space between insert into tbl & select. when i debug its stuck at currentdb.execute str_query.

Comment: Hi I worked it out. There was a extra , in the first select condition.after taking that out it started working. and 1 typo in table name too.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a space between Insert into tbl and Select. And another on the last line – `@chris neilsen`